# how to merge three dictionaries making 1 key have multiple separate list values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, data-structures

I am using Clarifai's API to get predictions from their Apparel, Color and texture model in a workflow. I am currently parsing the values from each of those models. The thing is I want to store the values of each of the predictions for an Input URL as separate row entries in a Dataframe.

So consider this URL

```
url="https://cdn.jooraccess.com/img/uploads/accounts/206679/images/322.30.S21_1100_1F-a6da8113cfee494cab07808e93889f44.jpg"
```

The predictions i get from this I separate into three dictionaries as

**Texture model**

```
tex_dict = {
    'https://cdn.jooraccess.com/img/uploads/accounts/206679/images/322.30.S21_1100_1F-a6da8113cfee494cab07808e93889f44.jpg': [
        'Texture Model', 'leather', 'quilted', 'studded'
                                               'knit', 'dandelion', 'rust', 'felted', 'shibori']}

color_dict = {
    'https://cdn.jooraccess.com/img/uploads/accounts/206679/images/322.30.S21_1100_1F-a6da8113cfee494cab07808e93889f44.jpg': [
        'Color Model',
        '#696969, DimGray',
        '#ffffff, White',
        '#2f4f4f, DarkSlateGray']}
```

and

```
apparel_dict = {
    'https://cdn.jooraccess.com/img/uploads/accounts/206679/images/322.30.S21_1100_1F-a6da8113cfee494cab07808e93889f44.jpg': [
        'Apparel Model', 'Cross Body Bag', 'Satchel', 'Laptop ag', 'Tote Bag', 'Cross Body Bag', 'Satchel',
        'Laptop Bag', 'Wristlet & Clutch', 'Tote Bag']}
```

What I am trying to do is to add these as three separate entries in a Pandas data frame. I want 1 URL to have 3 entries for three different models. There are about 30 URLS I am running them on

```
  URL  | Model Name | tag1 |tag2 |........tag n|
  URL A| color.     | tag1 |tag2 |........tag n|
  URL A| texture    | tag1 |tag2 |........tag n|
  URL A| Apparel    | tag1 |tag2 |........tag n|
  URL B| color.     | tag1 |tag2 |........tag n|
  URL B| texture    | tag1 |tag2 |........tag n|
  URL B| Apparel    | tag1 |tag2 |........tag n|
  URL C| color.     | tag1 |tag2 |........tag n|
  URL C| texture    | tag1 |tag2 |........tag n|
  URL C| Apparel    | tag1 |tag2 |........tag n|
```

how can I achieve this.

Comment: post the expected output you just posted some column names that didn't match your dictionary keys

Comment: added the outputs. Thanks for that catch

Comment: are you creating 30 * 3 dicts for 30 urls?

Comment: Do all dicts have roughly the same amount of tags? You could build a series instead of a df, with the key and first value as index

Comment: Yes. 30*3 dicts for those URLs. 
the tags are variable

Comment: hi there, did any of the answers work?

Comment: @RichieV This is how i did it 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63331138/4451893

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the dicts in a list you can build a dict comprehension that pandas can recognize

```
df = pd.DataFrame({list(d.keys())[0]: list(d.values())[0] 
    for d in list_with_dicts}).T.reset_index()
```

Now rename the columns

```
df.columns = ['url', 'column2'] + ['tag' + str(i) for i in range(1, df.shape[1] - 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it. It was a bit of a workaround but it worked.

1. I got all the predictions in a data frame by writing them to a dictionary.
2. Then I grouped the rows in the columns. Since each URL had 3 prediction rows, sorting them by the URL grouped them together.